# Are the fan patterns out of Pressure Washer nozzles always uneven? Strong at the edges and weak in the center?

Tags: pressure-washer

1st power washer and I got a SunJoe SPX3000, but I'm having the same problem with all of the nozzles ... the spray pattern is very strong at the 'edges' of the fan, and weak in the middle:

[image]

If I move the spray close enough to the surface that the center cleans as well then those 'lines' get strong enough to start stripping the paint. Is this normal? Are the nozzles or something else about the machine off?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the nozzle shape since it is just a hose from the pump to the nozzle.  Unknown if sun joe uses special nozzle holders compared to other makes, but might be able to try a nozzle of another make if it will fit.  Is it a fan(line) or circle shape output?

Comment: Stripping aging paint under high pressure is certainly normal; it's one of the things a pressure washer is used for. If that isn't your intent, back off or use a normal hose sprayer.

Comment: @keshlam That stripping happens sometimes I get, but I expected the pressure to be even across the fan. The pic above IS what happens when I back off. Which leaves that nozzle (or my technique?) un-usable for that surface. But hose pressure isn't touching that muck, not even close.

To restate ... is that pattern normal? Do most or all pressure washers/nozzles with a fan pattern have much more pressure at the edges? Because if I just bought some bum nozzles I'll buy a new set. But if this is just how pressure washing is I'll work on my technique or something.

Comment: As someone else asked, what's the nozzle pattern? Circular nozzles do tend to emphasize the outer edges of the circle; fan should be closer to what you intended. But yes, cheap nozzles can be more uneven than higher quality ones, so a swap might be worth trying.

Comment: Sorry, pictured above is from the 25 degree green nozzle that came with the unit. But all the high pressure nozzles included with the sprayer seem to have the same feature. Soap works boss though.

Comment: Just a guess, nozzle is probably going back and forth in a line instead of a circle cone.  It spends more time at each end, maybe sticking a bit than in the centre.

Comment: turn the nozzle 90 degrees